# After Facebook login in ASP.net or C# i want to call to C# function

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, authentication

I'm developing an ASP.Net web. The page has a facebook login-button and i want when the user clicks on the button and gets logged in, call a C# function to show some elements of my page.

I had created  a facebook app and in the code from the page i put the facebook SDK login, but didn't work...

Anyone can help me please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is call a webservice on successful login

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // log in successful
        callWebService();
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } 
    else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
});
```

And then you can do/manipulate whatever you want in the webservice and success callback of the webservice!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot tell you that i'm beginner... 
I test to put an `alert('hello');` in the `if` when `response.status === 'connected'` but didn't works, and call to a WebService but didn't works too...


Thanks!!

Comment: In that case can you add the html for the page that you have the login button on??